# How to make Image as Planes default to Diffuse shader instead of principled BSDF to in 2.8x

Tags: image

In 2.79 adding an image as a plane had a simple Diffuse and Transparent shader node setup that reproduced the original image exactly however 2.83 has a different setup with an alpha input into the Principled BSDF shader that results in a hazy version of the image that would require additional modifications to replicate the original. In 2.79 replacing the Diffuse shader with Principled causes the same problem so using a straight Diffuse/Transparent node setup produces the better results without the need for extra adjustments.

Personally I edit images externally prior to adding to the scene rather than editing it within the scene. Is there a way to modify the default node setup to the way it was is 2.79 or add my own default?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the window that opens when you add "import images as planes", there is a **gear** icon on the top right. Click on it and you will quite a few options open for you.  The shortcut, as you might have guessed already, is <kbd>N</kbd>

By default, the material is set to use the the BSD principled shader, but you can change it to Shadeless or Emit.

It is there that you can choose to use Alpha channel.

If you have a series of pictures you an choose to load all of them with a certain offset.

Lastly you can set the size and orientation.

[image]

For images that are already imported just change the principled shader for whatever it shader you like, and blend happily ever after.

---

**EDIT:**

Comparing the files from the previous version (2.79) of the addon it is quite easy to modify it to use a Diffuse shader.

[image]

Find the **io_import_imates_as_planes.py** file located in the /scripts/addons folder, open it in a text editor and replace **all** mention of `Principled` with `Diffuse`, make sure you match Upper and Lowercase correctly.

Then on lines 1013 and 1014 replace

```
     if self.shader == 'PRINCIPLED':
        core_shader = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
```

with

```
   if self.shader == 'DIFFUSE':
        core_shader = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
```

on line 1024

replace

```
    if self.use_transparency:
        if self.shader == 'PRINCIPLED':
            node_tree.links.new(core_shader.inputs[18], tex_image.outputs[1])
        else:
            bsdf_transparent = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfTransparent')

            mix_shader = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixShader')
            node_tree.links.new(mix_shader.inputs[0], tex_image.outputs[1])
            node_tree.links.new(mix_shader.inputs[1], bsdf_transparent.outputs[0])
            node_tree.links.new(mix_shader.inputs[2], core_shader.outputs[0])
            core_shader = mix_shader
```

with

```
    if self.use_transparency:

        bsdf_transparent = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfTransparent')
        bsdf_transparent = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfTransparent')

        mix_shader = node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMixShader')
        node_tree.links.new(mix_shader.inputs[0], tex_image.outputs[1])
        node_tree.links.new(mix_shader.inputs[1], bsdf_transparent.outputs[0])
        node_tree.links.new(mix_shader.inputs[2], core_shader.outputs[0])
        core_shader = mix_shader
```

Be aware of the indentation change, as you are getting rid of a conditional `if` and `else` statements.

Save the file and enable the addon again.

Here's a version of the [modified file](https://mega.nz/file/zthHlR6J#pNsOOjToOZ53wHGe9a_6SN4daZwsNaTnqi_ky7_LXeo)

Comment: Sadly the default options don't solve my problem. "Principled" uses the principled shader default settings which cause the problem. "Shadeless" adds a complex node group and other alterations to the original image. No alpha defeats the purpose of adding an image with alpha. I only want the basic diffuse + transparent shaders that were the default in 2.79 so my already perfect pictures don't get altered on import

Comment: Oh, don't let perfection go to waste!. Just change the shader to a diffuse one in the material editor. But you could use blender 2.79 to create the perfect material, save the project and open it perfectly in 2.8.

Comment: I rely heavily on adding images as planes and although I am capable of continually changing shaders the whole point of my question was to reduce the additional steps that are now required in the latest version

Comment: The link is blocked by browser as "unsafe". Maybe add it to a more trustworthy site so I can check it out

Comment: See Updated answer.