# How do I fix the size and rotation of my pictures?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to make picture frames, but my pictures imports the wrong way. How do I fix this?

I just want to rotate (and rescale the one on the left) the pictures. So I would not like to rotate the frames. The frames are made to fit the pictures.

[image]

Comment: Is the import method "Import image as planes"?

Comment: I improted the pictures as a material.

Comment: For semi-automatic framing, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/193573/35559) might be of interest, together wit @susu's link from the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Open the UV tab like in the screenshot. Select the UV mesh by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in the left window.

Press <kbd>R</kbd>, and after press <kbd>9</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd>. It will rotate your UV 90 degrees. And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Well done. Congratulations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so mutch. it worked :)

Comment: What do you mean by *"Well it done."* (incomprehensible)? *"Well, it is done."*? *"Well done."*? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Select your object, tap on "Object Properties" (the orange rectangle) and then enter 90 in the "Rotation X" field:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. I just want to rotate the picture though, not the frame

Comment: i don't know how you got the image to your object, so please provide your blend file, then i can help you instead of guessing what you have done.

Comment: I would. I just don´t know how to do that.

Comment: open this https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Comment: thank you verry much :)